# ERROR: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector, why?

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am trying to build bar chart in a box() under a tabpanel.

Here is my code:

```
col1 <- c('upto30', '31-45','46-60','61-75', '76abv')
col2 <- c(10,20,30,40,50)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody(
      mainPanel(tabsetPanel(type = 'tab',
      tabPanel("",
      box("",
         barplot(col2)))))          )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I don't know why such an error hits while running app. 
Can anyone help on this error *"Text to be written must be a length-one character vector"*?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to render your plot in `server` instead of `ui`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(type = 'tab'),
                          tabPanel("",
                                   box("",
                                       plotOutput("myPlot")))))                                                     
))

server <- function(input,output){
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot(
    barplot(col2)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for this help.